# Eclipse compilation and make file

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse.  Despite its best efforts I got it to compile and run a 
Hello World program. I am now trying to bring in a simple program I wrote that worked on MS Visual Studio 2010.

A user in reddit learnprogramming said I was missing a quotation mark in my make file, but I am using automatic make files.  I don't know how to write my own and would rather work on the other 50 things wrong with the program.  The Eclipse make file help page is technobabble to me.

I think Eclipse is not trying to build the files in the correct order, but I cannot find how to change the build order or how to point it towards the correct file to begin with. When I created the files in Eclipse, I hit "New Class" and then just copied and pasted in the old files. There are no red or yellow flags in the left margin indicating there are any problems. The file with the main method is Tier.cpp, but I believe it's trying to start with Player.cpp.

The compiler error is the very user friendly and easy to read:

```
01:31:42 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project VanillaWoW ****
make all
Building file: ../VanillaWoWSource/Player.cpp  
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -I"C:\cpp\boost_1_66_0\boost" -I"C:\cyg\bin" 
    -I"C:\cyg\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\6.4.0\include" 
    -I"C:\cyg\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\6.4.0\include\c++"
    -I"C:\cyg\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\6.4.0\include\c++\backward"
    -I"C:\cyg\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\6.4.0\include\c++\x86_64-pc-cygwin"
    -I"C:\cyg\usr\include" -I"C:\cyg\usr\include\w32api"
    -I"c:\cpp\boost_1_66_0\" -I"C:\cyg\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.4.0\include\c++"
    -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"VanillaWoWSource/Player.d"
    -MT"VanillaWoWSource/Player.o"
    -o "VanillaWoWSource/Player.o" "../VanillaWoWSource/Player.cpp"  
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'  
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file  
make: *** [VanillaWoWSource/subdir.mk:26: VanillaWoWSource/Player.o] Error 1
```

I don't understand why it's throwing an error on line 26 of an object file that I didn't think it had fully even created yet.  I don't know what /bin/sh: -c refers to, and I don't know which file it's hitting the end of file on.

Full code is at :
https://docs.google.com/document/d/185sOHxk3wKAnl6N0oCSvlJZB7WUTY8gEtZCsLIr1q0o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Putting "rant" in the title is not a good way to make friends here. C++ is more low-level than Java and that complicates the build process because you can't just boil it down to a `.jar` file and be done with it. That being said, your gripe here is about your workflow, not C++ per-se. Figure out your build process and your problems won't be so annoying. Personally I find Java's build process to be quirky and extremely annoying compared to C++ but that's only because I don't do a lot of Java work, and I know that people have figured it out.

Comment: Using Eclipse on Cygwin is always going to cause pain; Visual C++ has a free edition that is going to be more user-friendly. Furthermore, if you delete your rant, post the actual makefile rather than a link, and format up your question better, you might get an answer, but as it is I suspect this question will soon disappear...

Comment: True, but I'm looking for a genuine response to the question of why even the simplest things in C++ are so difficult given that there must be a half million students worldwide grappling with the same problems I am.  (Although I'm not a student)

Comment: Why the simplest things are difficult is purely opinion based which is off-topic here. What you find difficult others may find simple and vice-versa. I write C++ code all day and have no difficulty. My pain starts when I need to open up Android Studio and look at Java. *shrug*

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is [*not* the place for rants](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Ok I removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I formatted up your error messages, I can see the problem:

```
-I"c:\cpp\boost_1_66_0\" -I"C:\cyg\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.4.0\include\c++"
```

Note the  `boost_1_66_0\"` - the trailing backslash escapes the quote character, so the text colouring goes wonky. Look where you set up paths and either remove the trailing backslash, or better, use forward slashes throughout. Windows will accept them, and you won't get bitten by mysterious escape problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why getting C++ set up is so difficult for you. It might have something to do with you using Eclipse -- it's really more of a Java IDE, and I'd suggest using something that's built for C++. When I was starting C++, I wrote with Code::Blocks and it worked great for me. I'd suggest switching to that.

C++ is a lower level language than Java. It's arguably more difficult to program in because of that. Although I do think the brunt of your issue is more because of the environment you're coding in.

Comment: I'll take a look at it when sourceforge comes back up